# Debug Assertion Failed at deleted allocated memory

Tags: c++

I'm in a relatively basic programming class and I'm getting an error I've never come across before. It's this:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:...sual Studio 2010\Projects\Comp Project\Debug\Comp Project.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Here's my code and the error pops up as the allocated memory is deleted it looks like

```
    //Shortest Path Version 1.01 IN PROGRESS
/*
    This program reads in node and arc data and interpretes it into a list which it can then use
    to calculate the shortest time or distance, depending on user prefrence, between two chosen
    nodes and send pack the path to the user
*/
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    //opening the files where the data is contained.
    ifstream arcfile;
    ifstream nodefile;
    arcfile.open("G:\\Programming\\Descrete Structures\\arcs2011.txt");
    nodefile.open("G:\\Programming\\Descrete Structures\\nodes2011.txt");

    //creating a class that will store the data relevent to locating the shortest path
    class Arc
    {
    public:
        unsigned short int FROM;                                //from node
        unsigned short int TO;                                    //to node
        double DISTANCE;                                        //distance in miles
        double TIME;                                            //travel time
    };

    //creating a class that will store the data relavent to the node path
    class Node
    {
    public:
        unsigned long int WIEGHT;                                //either time or distance
        unsigned short int FROM;                                //alternativly "via"
        bool* shortestKnown;

    };

    string s;                                                    //placeholder for irrelavent string data
    unsigned short int StartingNode;                            //user selected starting node
    unsigned short int EndingNode;                                //user selected ending node
    unsigned short int ARCSIZE = 0;                                //number of Arcs in arc file
    unsigned short int NODESIZE = 0;                            //number of Nodes in node file

    //////////////////////Begin reading in of Arc data and Node data/////////////////////

    //count number of registered arcs
    while(getline(arcfile,s))
    {
        ARCSIZE++;
    }
    cout<<ARCSIZE<<" line size of arcfile"<<endl;

    //count number of registered nodes
    while(getline(nodefile,s))
    {
        NODESIZE++;
    }
    NODESIZE++;                                                    //final incrementation for +1 format
    cout<<NODESIZE<<" line size of nodefile"<<endl;

    Arc* Arclist;                                                //array that will store all the arcs
    Arclist = new Arc[ARCSIZE];                                    //based on the size of the file
    string* Nodelist;                                            //array that will store the node names
    Nodelist = new string[NODESIZE];                            //based on the size of the file

    //reset the streams
    arcfile.close();
    nodefile.close();
    arcfile.open("G:\\Programming\\Descrete Structures\\arcs2011.txt");
    nodefile.open("G:\\Programming\\Descrete Structures\\nodes2011.txt");


    //loop through and save the arc data to an array
    for(int i=1;i<ARCSIZE;i++)
    {
        arcfile.ignore(1000,'\n');
        arcfile>>Arclist[i].FROM;
        arcfile>>Arclist[i].TO;
        arcfile>>Arclist[i].TIME;
        arcfile>>Arclist[i].DISTANCE;
    }
    //loop through and store node description. Node counting starts at 1 to link up easier with
    //the arcs. The NODESIZE has been increased by 1 to allow for this format.
    for(int i=1;i<NODESIZE;i++)
    {
        getline(nodefile,Nodelist[i],'\t');                        //store node data
        nodefile.ignore(1000,'\n');                                //ignore coordinates
    }

    //////////////////////Begin user interface portion of program////////////////////////////////

    cout<<"Arcs and Nodes loaded."<<endl;
    cout<<"Please select by node number a starting node and ending node."<<endl;
    cout<<"(Press any key to display the list)"<<endl<<endl;
    getch();

    //print out the node list with numarical values
    for(int i=1;i<NODESIZE;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" - "<<Nodelist[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Please select a starting node: ";
    cin>>StartingNode;
    cout<<endl<<"Please select an ending node: ";
    cin>>EndingNode;

    ////////////////////////SOME KIND OF ERROR OCCURS PAST THIS POINT///////////////////////

    //delete allocated memory
    delete Arclist;
    delete Nodelist;


    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These:

```
delete Arclist;
delete Nodelist;
```

should be:

```
delete [] Arclist;
delete [] Nodelist;
```

Or better yet, forget using dynamically allocated arrays, and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::vector` is not likely to be covered/allowed in a "basic programming class".

Comment: @Tomalak Well, it certainly should be. It's much more basic than doing your own memory management.

Comment: We're heading into off-topic territory, but suffice it to say: of _course_ it "should be", and of _course_ it isn't. :)

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly and makes sense. And yea std::vector has never even been mentioned let alone taught.

Answer (score 2):

```
Arclist = new Arc[ARCSIZE];
Nodelist = new string[NODESIZE];
```

and

```
delete Arclist;
delete Nodelist;
```

do not match, [which is an error](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.12).

You mean:

```
delete[] Arclist;
delete[] Nodelist;
```

Your environment is detecting that something is not matching between the allocation and de-allocation.

This is quite fortunate, actually, because the C++ Standard does not mandate any diagnostics; on yours and other platforms, this mistake could silently "work" and cause all manner of memory corruption issues!

Incidentally, your `main()` function **must** return `int` (though you can leave out the explicit `return 0;` if you like; it'll be done automatically for `main()` if you leave it out).

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple. If you use `new` for initializing an array, you must delete it with the `delete[]` statement.

So you must say

```
delete[] Arclist;
delete[] Nodelist;
```